# react-native-firebase messaging... onInitialNotification is always returning null

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am attempting to use react-native-firebase messaging to open my app from a 'quit' state. I have read the documentation and researched, but I am stumped. Below is the code I am currently using to send and receive notifications. The method `onInitialNotification` properly triggers when the app is opened from a quit state but it is returning `null` for the `remoteMessage`. I suspect that the data is not being sent to my phone or is not being accepted by iOS from the notification.

Regardless, the notification is being sent, i can open the app on click, but I am unable to open up a specific app screen from a closed state.

Here is the code block for the message handling.

```js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

const Root = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    });
 
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        console.log(
          'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
          remoteMessage,
        );
      });
  }, []);

  ...
};
```

Here is the code block for sending a message.

```js
admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(change.after.data().userKey)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          admin.messaging().send({
            token: doc.data().fcmToken,
            notification: {
              title: 'You have a new Comment',
              body: 'Check out your post now!',
            },
            data: {
              screen: 'Profile',
              // params: JSON.stringify(change.after.data()),
              // params: JSON.stringify(params),
            },
          });
 });
```

For context, this is a continuation of another question. Relevant documentation is available [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage).